# Use Background image and put scaffold on it

Tags: flutter, dart

It uses the background image for whole application.

So My plan is use `Stack` including backgroundimage and Scaffold on it.

In this code, it shows `Title.png` but dosent show `BackGround.png`

Where should I fix??

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image.asset('images/BackGround.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Image.asset('images/Title.png')
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is showing your "BackGround.png" image. But, "Title.png" image is overlay above it. That's why you're not able to view it.

To check out if it is rendered or not just replace your code as following,

```
home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Image.asset('images/Title.png')
            ),
          ),
          new Image.asset('images/BackGround.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Stack always renders his first child, then second and then so on. So, in your case, whichever background you want to upload above all, should be on top.

Comment: Thank you it shows the BackGround.png. however it covers the Title.png... maybe my first idea is `wrong`??

Comment: THank you very much , I added `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` finally it works as I intend.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Scaffold inside Container with a background image and use `Colors.transparent` for Scaffold's `backgroundColor` property like this:

```
Container(
  //your image here
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("assets/bg.jpg"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  //your Scaffold goes here
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    body: Container(),
  ),
);
```